# Jquerymobile Panel link problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, panel

i'm trying to configure a slide-panel jqm 1.3.1. I always created "one page-jqm"-Pages
one index.html and several

Now im trying to get the slide panel to work but when i add a second page, the page stuck in loading screen.

My code will explain what i mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- Page 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">


  <div id="header" data-theme="c" data-role="header">
    <a id="men" data-role="button" href="#menue" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left info">
    </a>

    <h3>Body Change</h3>

  </div>
  <div id="content" data-role="content">
    Test123
  </div>

  <div id ="footer" data-role="footer">
    footer
  </div>
  <div data-role="panel" id="menue" data-display="push" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="controlgroup">
      <h2>Menü</h2>
      <a href="#page1" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a>
      <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Erlaubte Lebensmittel</a>
      <a href="#page3" data-role="button">Verbotene Lebensmittel</a>
      <a href="#page4" data-role="button">Frühstück</a>

    </div>
  </div>
<div>


<!-- Page 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">


  <div id="header" data-theme="c" data-role="header">
    <a id="men" data-role="button" href="#menue" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left info">
    </a>

    <h3>Body Change</h3>

  </div>
  <div id="content" data-role="content">
    Test123
  </div>

  <div id ="footer" data-role="footer">
    footer
  </div>
  <div data-role="panel" id="menue" data-display="push" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="controlgroup">
      <h2>Menü</h2>
      <a href="#page1" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a>
      <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Erlaubte Lebensmittel</a>
      <a href="#page3" data-role="button">Verbotene Lebensmittel</a>
      <a href="#page4" data-role="button">Frühstück</a>

    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

I thank you all for your help in advance
cracker182

EDIT:  browser console shows :
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

EDIT2: I forgot to Close the page Divs, thank you very much [Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar)

Comment: you're using the same id for both panels. Use different ids.

Comment: done, but no change :( only the loading animation shows up.

Comment: How do you open the panel? Post all the code.

Comment: i open the panel via
    <div id="header" data-theme="c" data-role="header">
    <a id="men" data-role="button" href="#menue" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left info">

did you mean this?

Comment: if i remove the second page, the panel opens correctly, only the links will not open

Comment: you aren't closing both pages `</div>` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wB6DF/

Answer (score 0):

```
             I stripped your footer menu blocks and if you look at this structure it will probably help you out to why your page is not navigating to the next page... Be sure to take a look at the naming conventions as well                  pertaining to the anchor tags...     

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="de">
            <head>
            ...
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">

            <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

            </head>
            <body>
            <!-- Page 1 -->
            <section id="firstpage" data-role="page">
            <div id="header" data-theme="c" data-role="header">
            <a id="menu" data-role="button" href="#menue" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left info"></a>

            <h3>Body Change</h3>

            </div>
            <div id="content" data-role="content">
            <p>This is page 1</p>
            <p><a href="#secondpage">Go to second page</a></p>
            </div>

            <div id ="footer" data-role="footer">
            footer
            </div>

            <div>
            </section>

            <!-- Page 2 -->
            <div data-role="page" id="secondpage">


            <div id="header" data-theme="c" data-role="header">
            <a id="menu" data-role="button" href="#menue" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left info">
            </a>

            <h3>Body Change</h3>

            </div>
            <div id="content" data-role="content">
            this is page 2
            <p><a href="#firstpage">Go to first page</a></p>
            </div>

            <div id ="footer" data-role="footer">
            footer
            </div>
            <div>
```